# What's the Germanic word for "defendant"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Defendant in German: *Beklagte*

Defendant in Dutch: *Verweerder*

Swedish, Danish, Frisian and Icelandic also have their own unique Germanic word for it, whilst English uses a French variant of it.

My question is, does English have an actual Anglic/Germanic word for "*defendant*"? Our sister languages do so, why not us?

I looked for synonyms of "defendant", and Google came up with "accused, prisoner at the bar; appellant, litigant, respondent; suspect, suspected person". Do they even have the same meaning as "defendant"? Also, they don't sound Germanic.

Comment: Use a thesaurus to find the synonyms of "defendant", then check out their etymologies.

Comment: I did. Google came up with "accused, prisoner at the bar; appellant, litigant, respondent; suspect, suspected person". Do they even have the same meaning as "defendant"? Also, they don't sound Germanic.

Comment: What about  accused
    appellant
    defendant

    litigant
    offender

    prisoner
    suspect, or any of the others at thesaurus.com?  And did you Google `etymology suspect`, eg, to find their origins?

Comment: Google the etymologies of "beklagte" and "verweerder." "Defendant" might not seem like such an outlier in context.  *Verweerder* seems to have been formed within Dutch (~="weathered"), *beklagte* seems to have roots in MLG, and *defendant* derives from French and ultimately Latin.  They're just separate paths.

Comment: Suspect comes from Latin.

Answer (score 2):

In common use in AE, there is NO Germanic equivalent. I can't say with 100% certainty such a term does not exist, but even if it did, you'd never hear it in daily life. For all intents and purposes, "defendant" is THE only word.

Comment: After researching and researching, it looks like it is the only word.